# Slow PHP Session

Tags: php, memcached

A basic page page with just `session_start();` loads just fine, but once I've set something, for example `$_SESSION['pet']="dog";`, the page load time is around 5 seconds.

I'm using AWS's memcached server and the connection time to it from the EC2 instance is really fast. I'm not sure where the slow down is coming from.

The session.save_handler is set to memcached and session.save_path is set to xxx.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211

phpinfo also displays Registered save handlers as files user memcache memcached

**EDIT** :
I uploaded test files to demonstrate the issue. The first file is simply `session_start(); print_r($_SESSION);` (http://rr915webapi.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/session.php). The second file is `session_start();$_SESSION['pet']="dog";$_SESSION['name']="bob";`(http://rr915webapi.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/session-set.php). After you load the second file, you can see the first takes a while longer to load than initially did.

Comment: Is the session stored in memcache or on disk?

Comment: I've set the session.save_handler to memcached and session.save_path to the ElastiCache instance - Under session it lists Registered save handlers: files user memcache memcached

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's truely using the memcached server?

Comment: @austinhollis http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php you can also just dump <?php phpinfo(); into a file and it will dump your config to a readable page.

Comment: @NeilMasters I did do that and didn't know if the order of Registered save handlers meant it was using something other than the session.save_path that is specified

Comment: @NeilMasters I added 2 files so you can see the issue. First is session_start() and print_r($_SESSION); (http://rr915webapi.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/session.php) The second adds data to the session http://rr915webapi.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/session-set.php. Once you load the second and go back to the first, you'll see how long it takes to load the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities :

- if your PHP server running your PHP code and your memcached server / cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com are hosted on different regions, it can explain all this time...
- there seems to be a a bug in libmemcached 1.0.16...if you update to 1.0.18, will fix the problem, see https://github.com/iuscommunity/wishlist/issues/143 comments and https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1589344

Comment: They're both in us-east-1, but they are in different zones. Would that still make a difference?

Comment: I just moved the EC2 instance to us-east-1b to see if that would make a difference, but I'm still getting the same 5 seconds until the first byte

Answer (score 5):

By setting the following in the PHP ini file, the response time was reduced down to milliseconds.

```
session.lazy_write = 0
memcached.sess_locking = Off
```